# Need help troubleshooting dhcpd during boot

Tags: boot, networking, dhcp

I’m trying to get isc-dhcp-server working on a headless Ubuntu 14.04 machine and I’ve run into some problems as documented in another thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838169/why-does-my-ubuntu-dhcp-isc-dhcp-server-service-fail-on-re-boot). I haven’t had any response yet so I’ve been trying different things and I have even more questions.

As indicated in the other thread, I can get isc-dhcp-server working briefly. I have the Ubuntu server connected to a router that’s configured as a DHCP server. Once it starts, I shut off the router’s DHCP service and re-start the isc-dhcp-server service on the Ubuntu machine and it begins giving out IP addresses in the range I configured, so all is well. When I reboot my Ubuntu machine however, the DHCP service doesn’t come back up. I figured there may be a problem with eth0 not being ready in time for the start up of the dhcpd service during the boot sequence, so I wanted to try booting without the isc-dhcp-server service, which leads to my first question:

How do I prevent the isc-dhcp-server service from starting on boot?

I’m running Ubuntu 14.04, but it’s not using upstart.

```
dpkg -S /sbin/init
```

indicates:

```
systemd-sysv: /sbin/init
```

I removed isc-dhcp-server from init.d but pgrep dhcpd shows it’s running when I boot. How can that be? Does some other service start it somehow? How can I tell? syslog hasn’t helped me. I did notice some references in /etc/init.d/.depend.start and /etc/init.d/.depend.stop but I don’t know what they mean, for example dnsmasq is listed in those files too, but I’ve purged dnsmasq. (BTW I also removed isc-dhcp-server.conf and isc-dhcp-server6.conf from /etc/init)

As I was troubleshooting the problem, I decided to try changing the IP address of my Ubuntu machine from 10.0.0.2 to something outside of the DHCP range of the router, so I modified /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 10.0.0.200
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 10.0.0.0
   broadcast 10.0.0.255
   gateway 10.0.0.1
```

ifconfig on my Ubuntu machine indicates the 10.0.0.200 IP address is assigned but the router still shows 10.0.0.2! I can also ssh into my Ubuntu server using 10.0.0.2.

How can the router show an IP address for the Ubuntu machine that’s different from what ifconfig reports?

Troubleshooting tips most welcome!